# How can I see a list of files that are ignored but Added?

Tags: plasticscm

Scenario:

Check in files.

Add line to ignore.conf.

Now you want to see if any of the files that you checked in previously would have been affected by the new line in ignore.conf.

Is there a way to do this through either the GUI or `cm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to prune your workspace and leave it without the items that should't be part of the repository but unfortunately they are.

I found a way to do it, you'll need to execute the following commands from the workspace root directory. Check if it works for you.

```
dir . /b /s /A-D /o:gn  | cm rm - --nodisk
cm status --ignored --short | cm checkin -
cm unco --all
```